# Exec vs source error on ==

Tags: bash, shell-script

I run a strange error with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a="a"
b="a"

if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
then
  echo "Eq"
fi
```

`chmod u+x script.sh`

Then executing the file will display `Eq`:

```
$ ./script.sh
Eq
```

But sourcing it results in an error:

```
$ source script.sh
script.sh:6: = not found
```

Do you know what can cause this error?

Comment: What shell do you source the script into?

Comment: zsh, I plan on using this script at shell-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sourcing the script, your current shell executes the commands. In zsh, you must use a single `=` in comparison.

```
$ echo '[ a == a ]' | zsh
zsh: = not found
exit code: 1
$ echo '[ a = a ]' | zsh
$
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense, if I want to force the shell to execute the sourcing, won't the shebang line be enough ?

Comment: @Nobe4: sourcing ignores the shebang line. It makes no sense to source to a different shell: sourcing is used to run the commands in the current shell, so how can you run the commands in the current shell in a different shell?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The shell that is running the (sourced) code is not bash.

if the code you present is inside a file called `script.sh`, then this errors will appear:

```
$ dash ./script.sh
./script.sh: 6: [: a: unexpected operator
$ zsh ./script.sh
./script.sh:6: = not found
```

That seems to confirm that you are using a zsh prompt, and sourcing the script. To reproduce:

```
$ zsh
$ . ./script.sh
./script.sh:6: = not found
```

That will not happen if the interactive shell is bash:

```
$ bash
$ . ./script.sh
Eq
```

Also, it would be better if you use a shebang of `#!/bin/bash` (not that it changes what I just explained, but worth to mention).